# ModalPopup inside another modalpopup postback close issuse

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopup

I have a modal popup. When i click on a button in this popup, another popup show up. 
But on the second popup, each time I click a button, the popup disappear, and I must click on the button of first modal popup to show it up again.
I've already put a UpdatePanel inside Panel of popup control but it doesn't seem to work.
More detail.
I created 2 user controls, 1 for looking up and another for editing data.
And I'm creating another 2 user control with modal popup inside.
First modal popup: has a multi view with look up control and edit control.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelMain">
    <asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:MultiView>
            <asp:View>
                <Lookup Control>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View>
                <Edit Control>
                // this edit control contains second modal popup
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender PopupControlID="panelMain" />
```

Second modal popup: only has look up control.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelMain">
    <asp:UpdatePanel>
        <Lookup Control>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender PopupControlID="panelMain" />
```

The look up control has button to search, etc and might trigger postback event.
Is there anyway so I can prevent the second popup from closing after each click?
Sorry for my bad english because it's not my mother language.
Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but it will referesh the page when ever you click a button inside model popup and it will close itself.

Comment: Thanks for response. I known the button cause postback event, so I put the whole content of the popup inside an update panel, it should work as it did for the first popup modal. But I don't know why it doesn't work with the second one.